# Comparing two graphviz.Digraph objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, graphviz, pygraphviz

I have two digraphs in the form:

```
dot1 = graphviz.Digraph(format='svg')
dot1.attr('node', shape = 'box')


dot2 = graphviz.Digraph(format='svg')
dot2.attr('node', shape = 'box')
```

How can I compare these two digraphs? By comparing I mean I find the uncommon nodes and uncommon edges between similar nodes?

The nodes of these graphs have names, ie. "add".

I would appreciate any suggestions or thoughts on this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do that using the `graphviz` module by itself; this module is primarily concerned with *generating* dot output, rather than parsing dot syntax and providing a structured API.

TThe [`pygraphviz`](https://pygraphviz.github.io/) can probably do what you want. With this in place, we can do this:

```
>>> import graphviz
>>> import pygraphviz as pgv
>>> dot1 = graphviz.Digraph(format='svg')
>>> dot1.node('node1')
>>> dot1.node('node2')
>>> dot1.edge('node1', 'node2')
>>> g = pgv.AGraph(string=str(dot1))
```

And now that we've parsed the dot syntax, we can ask for a list of nodes:

```
>>> g.nodes()
['node1', 'node2']
```

Or a list of edges:

```
>>> g.edges()
[('node1', 'node2')]
```

And that should be sufficient for you to perform the comparison you were asking about.